# Как в i3 менять язык

Tags: linux, manjaro, i3wm

Поставил на виртуалку manjaro i3
При установке как обычно указал русский язык. Установка там как в Ubuntu в принципе.

Всё вроде норм установилось. Открываю терминал клавишами Windows + Enter
Проблема в том что по умолчанию русский язык печатает. И никак не могу английски найти.
Стандартные сочетания перепробовал:

- Alt+Shift
- Ctrl+Shift
- Windows+пробел

Закрыть терминал вроде Windows+Shift+q но так как русский язык то вместо закрытия он печатает "Й"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь гуглить "основные сочетания клавишь i3" --- там всё что угодно только не смена языка.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Оконные менеджеры не имеют никакого отношения к языкам

Comment: нужно было при установке ставить русский но раскладку клавиатуры выбирать английскую, но а после установки уже настроить переключение как нужно

Comment: @Zt.  спс! помогло!

Answer (score 1):

[первый вариант.](https://igancev.ru/2021-10-31-i3wm-keyboard-layout#%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

[второй вариант.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/i3_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88)